# Can ArcGIS Desktop 9 and 10 co-exist peacefully on same computer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3, installation

We have a copy of Hawths tools that only work in ArcGIS 9.3, so I would like to keep it on my computer. However, most of the work we do in our lab is done with ArcGIS 10.

Therefore, would it be OK to install both ArcGIS 9 and 10 on the same computer? If so, can you give and tips/experience on how to best achieve that?

Comment: It can if you have a Virtual Machine Installed - http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html We run Windows 7 (ArcGIS10) and a Windows XP VM (ArcGIS 9.3) Virtual Machine - http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [help file](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis10/common-questions.html) says:

> **Can ArcGIS 10 be installed on the same machine as ArcGIS 9.3.1?**
>
> No. For users who want to install ArcGIS 10 and ArcGIS 9.3.1 on the same machine, Esri recommends using a virtualization tool (such as VM Ware's VM Workstation or Microsoft's Virtual PC) and install the new instance of ArcGIS on that virtual machine.
>
> We had initially announced that we would be able to support running ArcGIS 10 and ArcGIS 9.3.1 on the same machine. However, we were not able to accomplish this for ArcGIS 10.

(FWIW, I'm successfully running Hawth's Tools in ArcMap 10. Although it's not listed as being supported at this version, it *seems* to work.)

Comment: +1 BTW, looks like [Hyper-V will be part of Windows 8 client](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/07/bringing-hyper-v-to-windows-8.aspx).

Comment: Thanks so much, and for letting me know that Hawth's Tools work in your case.

Comment: I just tried installing Hawth's Tools in ArcMap 10.1 and this also seems to have worked.